# How separate hadoop secondary namenode from primary namenode?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, mapreduce, filesystems, distributed

all

I want to ask, now I'm running hadoop 2.6.0. So how can I separate this secondary namenode from the primary one? What's the configuration?

Have I use one additional computer to become a secondary namenode, or it can be in a datanode?

I need your suggest, thanks...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303950/hadoop-2-x-how-to-configure-secondary-namenode

Answer (score 2):

NameNode, Secondary NameNode, DataNodes are just names given to "machines" based on the job they perform. In a "ideal" distributed enviornment, they all can and should reside in separate machines.

The only requirement for a secondary NameNode to be on another machine is : Secondary NameNode and NamdeNode should be connected so that The FSImane & EditLogs can be copied from NameNode to Secondary NameNode.

Comment: thanks mr Omkar, I want to ask again, but this one is quite long hahaha. How can I declare a machine is a secondary namenode. If we want to declare namenode, so we can write it in "master" file, and if we want to declare datanode, so we can write it in "slave" file, and so how about secondary?

And second how can we connect secondary and primary namenode to FSImage & EditLogs?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: In hdfs-site.xml :


<property>
 <name>dfs.secondary.http.address</name>
 <value>$secondarynamenode.full.hostname:50090</value> 
 <description>Enter your Secondary NameNode hostname</description>
</property>

Comment: this configuration on namenode or secondary node? and the secondary namenode we register on master or slave file? thanks2